# How can a comment change the output of the program?

Tags: c

I am just a newcomer to the C language. I am using code6.4 for exercising C.
See the code behind.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[5]={1,4,7,3,5};

    merge(a, 0, 2, 4);
    printf("%d",a[4]);

    return 0;
}

void merge(int *a ,int p ,int q,int r){
    int n1,n2;
    n1=q-p+1;
    n2=r-q;
    int temp1[n1];
    int temp2[n2];
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
        temp1[i]=a[p+i];
    }
    for (i=0; i<n2; i++) {
        temp2[i]=a[q+1+i];
    }
    j=0;
    k=0;
    for (i=p; i<=r; i++) {
        if (temp1[j]<temp2[k]) {
            a[i]=temp1[j];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            a[i]=temp2[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d ",a[4]);
}
```

So the output of this is:

> 7 7

I have uploaded the screen capture.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfhFD.png]

But when I comment out the second printf:

```
 for (i=p; i<=r; i++) {
    if (temp1[j]<temp2[k]) {
        a[i]=temp1[j];
        j++;
    }
    else{
        a[i]=temp2[k];
        k++;
    }
 }
 //printf("%d ",a[4]);
```

The output of the first printf has changed. Like the picture below.

> -1231562870

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NPlw.png]

I know this could be ridiculous, but anyone could help me?

Comment: Just to get that clear: you comment out a `printf` and wonder why the output of your program changes? Huh?? Please read a C book!

Comment: `//` is a comment and don't execute in the code. It's only for your reference. and you can type anything in a line after `//`

Comment: I have *actually* looked at the images (why would you post code and text in general as images???), and it smells like UB.

Comment: Yes. The first comment changed its output.

Comment: **Do not post images if not necessary.** Post the code instead.

Comment: @Olaf The code is already there. The images show that the code indeed produces that output.

Comment: We would have also believed you without the bombasto screen shots.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time for me to pose a question there , I just want to make it more detailed.

Comment: @melpomene: I see. So OP bloated the question by two screenshots just to show two integer values? Great reason to post images instead of just two lines of text.

Comment: @Y.Yui: Detailed is good in general, but you confuse quality with quantity.

Comment: Before posting to any resource you first need to check the local culture in order to post in a right way. Now your post is just collecting downvotes and on its way to oblivion.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for pointing out this , I won't post images if it isn't necessary next time.

Comment: @Olaf Again, not instead of, but in addition to. And I am to blame for inlining the images; they were just links before. I was trying to clarify the question because your first comment shows you completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @melpomene: I see. And how do they contribute to understanding? They are hard to read, they contain the same functions and to find the result you have to search. (I very well noticed that before). Btw.: To know why I wrote the first comment, you should read the original version of the question. Bad enough context is lost now, but you should check timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior here:

```
if (temp1[j]<temp2[k]) { ... }
```

In your specific example, it happens when `i == r`, since you'll be comparing `temp1[2]` with `temp2[2]`, but `temp2` has 2 elements only, so that's an out of bounds access.

Attempting to reason about programs with UB is frowned upon; fix the mistake and that should stop you from having other surprises.

One possible fix is to change the last loop to:

```
for (i=p; i<=r; i++) {
    if (k < n2 && j < n1) {
        if (temp1[j] < temp2[k]) {
            a[i] = temp1[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            a[i] = temp2[k];
            k++;
        }
    } else if (k < n2) {
        a[i] = temp2[k];
        k++;
    } else {
        a[i] = temp1[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't I say that? :-)

Comment: @alk Yes, you did, I'm baffled as to why it was downvoted (if you were wondering, no, it wasn't me, I was just as surprised as you, but I'll give you the upvote!).

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves  Yes I got that. Therefore removed my comment .